# script to fetch instances from auto scaling group and in turn fetch host name of that instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

i need to provide hostname for one of the EC2 metric: for that i need to fetch the hostname through script.

please help me with a script which  fetches all the instances from autoscaling group and loop through each instance until it matches the hostname

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show us what you have done so far and where you struggle at ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "hostname"? Are you referring to the Name that appears in the EC2 console (which is the value obtained from the `Name` tag), or are you referring to the hostname used by the Operating System running on the instance? Why did you label your question with CloudFormation? Please Edit your question to provide more information rather than answering in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of *all* Auto Scaling instances (regardless of Auto Scaling group), you can use [describe-auto-scaling-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-instances.html).

If you want a list of instances associated with a specific Auto Scaling group, you can use [describe-auto-scaling-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-auto-scaling-groups.html), which also returns a list of each instance in the group.

Then, for each instance that is returned, you can call [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html), which includes Tags in the response. The `Name` tag contains the name of the instance.